# What are the issues to be considered while creating a Robust Multi-threaded Scalable application in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, network-programming, thread-safety, threadpool

I am planning to build a stand-alone / web based Java application. It should be capable of handling thousands of requests at a moment. Request messages come in through a TCP port say 6040. I have a dedicated thread to constantly listen for messages from clients. Once the message is read from the socket this thread will spawn a thread to service a request. So its basically one thread per request.

Servicing the request involves many database operations like calling stored procedures in remote databases, performing updates/insertions in local database and also logging. A response should be sent to the client after servicing the request.

I hope the scenario is clear. In short I want to build a robust multithreaded scalable application (to use the cliche). My questions are as follows:

1. Should the main thread listening to incoming requests spawn a thread for each request or should it just take one from a thread pool. What I'm asking is should I use Thread Spawning  or Thread Pooling in my application.
2. Is it possible to deploy a standalone java application on clusters?
3. Is it a good idea to deploy and run it with the web-application (deployed on JBoss 7.1 server), which I intend to develop for administration purposes or should it be a standalone application?
4. In general what are the issues to be considered while building a Robust Multi-threaded Scalable applications in java

Comment: What do you mean by "club it"? Do you mean run it on the same machine? Or in the same process? Or something else?

Comment: Run in on the same server instance along with the web-app

Comment: Why are you re-building something that's been built many, many times already? What is lacking in existing implementations?

Comment: Could you please be more Specific Dave?

Answer (score 2):

To ensure that your Java application should scale, there's basically one simple rule to follow: Don't share state.

All state should be local to the thread or in the backing datastore.  This ensures that you can spin up unlimited copies of your application (on the same machine or not) that are entirely independent, and use a simple load balancer in front.

To answer your thread question specifically, it's almost always better to use an appropriately configured thread pool.  You avoid the overhead of spawning the thread inline to your request and you can configure reasonable limits to avoid resource contention / exhaustion.

Comment: By saying "Don't share state" what do you mean? Avoid Inter-thread communication right?

Comment: @hari I believe he means avoid sharing mutable data between threads. (Or at least minimise it and manage it carefully)

Comment: @PeterLawrey : Thanks, I was planning to avoid that. The database will hold the state of the thread.

Comment: This makes the database shared state. Using a database instead of in-memory state is likely to be slower.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Threadpools rather than spawning a Thread when the request arrives to save some response time. Additionally, you could use non-blocking IO (check [New I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O) to have a single thread monitor many connections. Also, what Steven Schlansker said: don't share state!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it really deserves to build it from scratch. From productivity perspective, it'll be much quicker to reuse existing web-container, like Jetty, Tomcat, etc. If you follow the Servlet API, you only need to describe your business logic, and container will deal with concurrency for you.

It takes a lot of time to tune performance of a web-container. Even large companies choose Tomcat/Jetty, such as Google's App Engine.

Comment: If its a standalone app i'll have to build from scratch. If i deploy it in Web-COntainer like Tomcat/Jetty/JBoss, What i need to know is whether the web-container will handle load-balancing on the requests to the specific port (say 6040).

Comment: Yes, if you deploy it to a web-container, the container will handle load-balancing among all worker threads. Basically, most containers put http requests to a task queue/pool, where all worker threads can pick a new task after previous task finished.